# Generic subscript with constraints on associated type leads to "Cannot subscript a value of type..."

Tags: swift, dictionary, generics, associated-types

Using Swift 4.2, I'm trying to write a generic system to get rid of strings as key of dictionaries to use enums instead.

Here is what I came with:

```
extension Dictionary where Key == String {
    subscript<T : RawRepresentable>(key: T) -> Value? where T.RawValue == String {
        get { return self[key.rawValue] }
        set { self[key.rawValue] = newValue }
    }
}
```

This compiles, and is destined to take any `RawRepresentable` type with a `String` raw value as key to the subscript for every `Dictionary` with `String` as key.

Unfortunately when I do the following, it does not compile:

```
enum MovieKey: String {
    case movieId = "movie_id"
    case movies = "movies"
}

var dic = [String:String]()
dic[key: MovieKey.movieId] = "abc123" // error
```

I get the following compilation error: `Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : String]' with an index of type '(key: MovieKey)'`

Except if I'm mistaken, `dic` is a `Dictionary` with `String` as key, and `MovieKey` is `RawRepresentable` and the raw value is `String` typed...

If someone can explain what I'm doing wrong, thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm just a swift n00b, but shouldn't that be `dic[MovieKey.movieId] = "abc123"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you aren't using subscript correctly. You shouldn't be supplying any argument labels to the subscript call, simply supply the `enum` value.

`dic[MovieKey.movieId] = "abc123"` compiles just fine.